# Synchronize user profile service with SQL Server Database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, forms-authentication, synchronisation

I have a web application that has user credentials stored in SQL Server database(Form Based Authentication). I need to synchronize the user profile service application with the SQL Server database.

Please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use BCS(BCS can only be used for property augmentation). You have to do follow things

- creating external content types from data in Microsoft SQL Server
  tables
- creating synchronization connections
- mapping user profile properties
- Run Full Synchronization.

Please follow this video from MSFT, to complete task.
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/technet/en-us/office/media/video/video.html?cid=stc&from=mscomSTC&videoid=ede7d855-035c-47a9-9492-1c2a23614a4a

also check this:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/03/18/how-to-create-userprofile-synchronization-connection-to-bcs-and-map-user-profile-property-to-bcs-field-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx